# PHP - MYSQL order multiple tables by date

Tags: php, mysql, sql

The first table called posts looks like:

```
id || username || post        || time
 1 || test_123 || Hello world || 1
 9 || test_123 || Hi world    || 3
```

The second table called likes looks like

```
id || username_like || post_id || time
 1 || test_123      || 4       || 2
 2 || test_123      || 10      || 4
```

I'm trying to find a correct query that will order both tables depending on time

I've already tried several queries, none of them worked, one of them is

```
$query = "SELECT post, post_id 
          FROM posts 
          LEFT JOIN likes 
          WHERE username='$log_username' OR username_like='$log_username' 
          ORDER BY time";
```

I want something like

```
Hello world (post) || 4 (post_id) || Hi world (post) || 10 (post_id)
```

They are order by the column time in both tables

Comment: you need to specify what the join is on

Comment: Well, if you can understand the problem, then please show me how I can do to find the results I'm trying to find

Comment: Since both tables have a `time` column, you need to specify `tablename.time` in the `ORDER BY` clause.

Comment: I don't think we can understand the problem. What is the desired output supposed to be?

Comment: Hello world (post)     ||      4 (post_id)      ||       Hi world (post)       ||       10 (post_id)    They are order by the column time in both tables

Comment: Please add the desired output to your question.

Comment: Good. Now explain how you got this output. What logic did you use?

Comment: both tables have the column time and as you can see in posts there are rows that have (1-3) and in likes there are rows that have (2-4) so all I want is to order these 4 rows by time , so that I get (1-2-3-4). And a good example for this may be notifications in facebook, if you would go to notifications, you will see different kinds of notifications like "someone commented" "someone liked" and they are all ordered by time

Comment: Per your posted data, you never going to get the desired output since the match is not present.

Comment: How many columns should the output have? Please make sure that your desired output includes all the relevant rows / fields.

Comment: Look at this [**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/07444/2). Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: @PM77-1 created a SQL Fiddle that shows the result can be easy if the resulting values are expected to be in a column. That solution relies on your `post` and `post_id` columns having the same definitions in your database (or being CAST() to the same definition), and it still doesn't present the four values in a single row. But it's not yet very clear if a "single row" is really what you want. That's a bit more complicated.

Comment: YES definitely, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

join you must have **on** clause i call second table is **posts_second**, if two table ambiguous column name you must specific your table name.you replace posts_second with your table name and try

```
 SELECT post, post_id 
          FROM posts 
          LEFT JOIN posts_second on posts.username= posts_second.username_like
          WHERE username='$log_username' OR username_like='$log_username' 
          ORDER BY posts.time
```

Comment: I believe you're too quick in your assumptions.